# F# - Recursive function to copy a list

Tags: list, f#

I wrote this code to recursively copy my list:

```
let sp = [2;4;6;8;10]
let copy (s1:'a list) =
let rec copy acc ind = 
    if(ind>=0) then
        copy (s1.[ind]::acc) (ind-1)
    else acc
copy [] (s1.Length-1)


sp |> copy |> printfn "%A"
```

How to make this code easier?

Comment: Make it more like the recursive sum function

Comment: What exactly do you mean by easier? More optimized? Easier to read?

Comment: You have to solve an exercise or a real problem?

Comment: Lists in F# are immutable, so there (usually) isn't a reason to copy them.  What bigger-picture problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performing a lookup into the list (as well as getting the length of the list) is not very efficient, because the library needs to iterate over the entire list (or over the first N elements). For this reason, doing this is not really idiomatic in F#.

You can still keep most of the structure of your code, but change it a little like this:

```
let copy input =
  let rec copy acc input =
    match input with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | x::xs -> copy (x::acc) xs
  copy [] input
```

The changes are:

- We use pattern matching on the input and always get the first element
- Since we append items to `acc` in reverse order, we call `List.rev` to reverse the result at the end (which is a standard trick when working with lists)